# Why two unicode-characters are not allowed in xkb?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, xkb

I wonder why a sequence of Unicode-characters is not allowed on one key-press in xkb. eg. I use Indian keyboard for typing in Devanagari. This keyboard is based on the [inscript keyboard layout](http://sanskrit.indiatyping.com/images/sanskrit-Inscript-Layout.jpg). In this layout, there are 4 characters (let's say complex characters) which are not found in the xkb version (Indian). Those characters are composed of three characters and if one wants to type them, he/she is supposed to type all three of them. The characters and there composition is as follows -

1. त्र = त (U0924) + ् (U094D) + र (U0930)
2. श्र = श (U0936) + ् (U094D) + र (U0930)
3. ज्ञ = ज (U091C) + ् (U094D) + ञ (U091E)
4. क्ष = क (U0915) + ् (U094D) + ष (U0937)

In other operating-systems this layout works fine. Why it does not work in Linux? What has to be done to allow this kind of programming?

Comment: You may need an input method to do that. For instance, you can install `ibus-m17n` and (after having re-logged in) select _Hindi (inscript (m17n))_.

Comment: Oh great! Can I also see the code of the keyboard, like I can see of x11?

Comment: I'm not able to explain details about how to use it. Just wanted to point at input methods as a way to overcome the XKB limitations you mentioned.